# laravel 4 filter route not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, filter

I have an admin section in my app which works fine, however now I want to close it so only admin has access. Basically I want to redirect to `admin/login` if a non-admin person is trying to access admin pages.

This is my admin route (which works):

```
Route::controller('admin', 'AdminController');
```

I tried adding the following filter above the `admin` controller route, and I also commented out the `local` array element so the environment is set to production, but it is just not working.

Routes.php

```
Route::filter('isAdmin', function()
{
    if ( ! Session::has('admin') ) {
        return Redirect::to('admin/login');
    }
});

Route::get('admin', array('before' => 'isAdmin', function() 
{
    echo 'You are over 200 years old!';
}));

Route::controller('admin', 'AdminController');
```

So if now I go to mysite/admin , I still get to admin dashboard even though `session admin` does not exist.

Comment: Why not set a new column on users called "admin" as a boolean, then you can do `auth()->user()->admin`? Then you're not having to rely and set sessions when someone logs in.

Comment: I dont have a users table plus not sure how I would do that and I just want to do this simple thing manually.

Comment: How are you setting the session when a user logs in then? And have you tried putting a `dd('here')` within the filter to make sure it's actually being called?

Comment: Have you also made sure that you definitely don't have the session set already?

Comment: I am not setting the session yet, it's supposed to not be set so that it redirects. I am also new to laravel and not sure I am doing the filters thing correctly. I actually just wanted to redirect from controller's constructor but for some reason that gives me a redirect loop error.

Comment: I am sure the session is not set because there is no way as of yet to actually set it plus if I do a conditional in the constructor to echo something based on the session existing it acts as expected.

Comment: The next thing to check then is that the filter is in the right place. It should be added to app/filters.php assuming that you are using Laravel 4.2.

Comment: I also put the filters directly in the routes folder, not sure if it makes a difference.

Comment: Tried that as well, now I have filter in filter.php and the 2 routes in routes.php (Route::get and Route::controller), still not working.

Comment: Can you simply post an answer using my imaginary unset session which would redirect to admin/login whenever someone went to root/admin or any subsequent url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work, this is untested

**Filters.php**

```
Route::filter('isAdmin', function()
{
    if ( ! Session::has('admin'))
    {
        return Redirect::to('admin/login');
    }
});
```

**Routes.php**

```
Route::group(['before' => 'isAdmin'], function() 
{
    Route::get('admin', 'AdminController@index');
});
```

**AdminController.php**

```
<?php
class AdminController
{
    public function index()
    {
        echo 'they\'re an admin';
    }
}
```

Comment: This needs to work with any admin page not just index, I change the route inside route::group to `Route::controller('admin', 'AdminController');`.Now this DOES redirect to admin/login BUT the browser gives `This webpage has a redirect loop` error.

Comment: actually this is good for setting up filters, i was redirecting to a method inside the same controller hence the loop.